# Any two decompositions of semisimple modules are equivalent for the infinite case

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I have a question about the decomposition of semisimple modules.

Assume that $M$ is a left semisimple $R-$modules.

If $M=\oplus_{A}T_{\alpha}=\oplus_{B}S_{\beta}$, where $A$, $B$ are indexed set and $T_\alpha$,  $S_\beta$ are simple $R$-modules.

I want to prove that $\oplus_{A}T_{\alpha}$ and $\oplus_{B}S_{\beta}$ are equivalent, i.e. there exists $\sigma :A\rightarrow B$ is a bijection such that $T_\alpha\cong S_{\sigma(\alpha)}$.

Here are my atempts:

Firstly, we can get $\mathrm{card}(A)=\mathrm{card}(B)$ if we use the similar method from the vector space.

(If $V$  is a vector space, $X$ and $Y$ are basis of $V$ respectively, then $\mathrm{card}(X)=\mathrm{card}(Y).$

Then if $A$ is finite, I can get it by the Jordan-Holder theorem.

But if $A$ is finite, from $\mathrm{card}(A)=\mathrm{card}(B)$,  I can get a bijection $\phi$ from $A$ to $B$.

But this bijection maynot satisfy $T_\alpha\cong S_{\phi(\alpha)}$

How can I get the $\sigma$ I want?

Any help and references are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: @ Amateur_Algebraist  Thanks! The link is about the finite case. But I am confused about the infinite case.

Comment: I think the linked argument doesn't depend on finiteness of $A$ — the universal property holds for arbitrary direct sums.

Comment: Thanks! I get it.